# CSS - element has background color, but is also transparent

Tags: html, css

I have a menu structure, like this:

```
<nav id="main">
    <ul id="nav-user">
        <li class="user-name">
            <span class="name">John Doe</span>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Profile</li>
                <li>Settings</li>
                <li>Sign Out</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="nav-main">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>           
</nav>
```

I'm having an issue with `ul.submenu`. It's overlaying `ul#nav-main`, but for some reason it's transparent:

http://jsfiddle.net/JvALU/

I don't want to see the `ul#nav-main`. How can I change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z-index` can only be used with elements that are positioned `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. Try adding `position: relative;` to `ul.submenu`.

Hope this helps.